# Autofac and WebAPI - Default constructor error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have a webforms project, but am using WebAPI for web services. I am trying to implement Autofac. I am getting:

```
'MyController' does not have a default constructor
```

According to the Autofac documentation I have the configuration correct but obviously there is a problem. I am using Visual Studio 2010/.Net 4. Here is my Application_Start

```
private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This enables api controllers in a separate class library
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new AssembliesResolver());

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

    //Elmah for webapi
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorApiAttribute());

    var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
    json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    //Register DbContext
    builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>()
        .As<IMyDbContext>()
        .InstancePerRequest();    

    //Register service layer
    var businessLayer = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();

    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    var container = builder.Build();
    _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(container);

    var webApiResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);        
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = webApiResolver;       

}
```

A typical api controller looks like this:

```
 [Authorize]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public IMyService context { get; set; }

    public MyController(IMyService context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // GET api/dostuff
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of all dtos
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<MyDto> Get()
    {
        try
        {                
            return context.MyDtos.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = string.Format("{0} {1} HTTP/1.1 {2} Exception: {3}", Request.Method, Request.RequestUri, HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, ex.Message);
            var errorMessage = new System.Web.Http.HttpError(message) { { "ErrorCode", 405 } };
            throw new HttpResponseException(ControllerContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, errorMessage));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your service types are not loaded when you are trying to register them with `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())`. So try it with `BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()`: `builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies())`

Comment: It is getting the services because they are being injected successfully elsewhere in the project. Its only the WebAPI that's giving me problems.

Comment: Also, that does not fix the problem.

Comment: Do you have your apicontrollers in the same web project? If not you need to change `builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` to `builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(MyController).Assembly)`;

Comment: OK, that was it, but I need to register each ApiController? Also, if you put that as an answer I can mark it as 'the answer'.

Comment: No you need to call `builder.RegisterApiControllers` once with the assembly of the controllers because autofac will register all of your controllers from that assembly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have your api controllers in a different assembly than your web project, then you need to need to tell Autofac where to find your controllers with changning:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

To

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(MyController).Assembly);
```

This will instruct Autofac to scan the assembly of `MyController` and **register all** `ApiController` derived types what it founds there.