# Autofac: Type 'MyController' does not have a default constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a Web Api app that consumes another REST Api client. I wrapped the REST API client into a service.

**myproj/services/PostDataService.cs**

```
  public interface IPostDataService
    {
        Task<IList<Post>> GetAllPosts();
    }

    public class PostDataService : IPostDataService
    {
        private static IDataAPI NewDataAPIClient()
        {
            var client = new DataAPI(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dataapi.url"]));
            return client;
        }

        public async Task<IList<Post>> GetAllPosts()
        {
            using (var client = NewDataAPIClient())
            {
                var result = await client.Post.GetAllWithOperationResponseAsync();
                return (IList<Post>) result.Response.Content;
            }
        }
    }
 ....
```

I am using *AutoFac* and injecting the service in the controller

**myproj/controllers/PostController.cs**

```
public class PostController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IPostDataService _postDataService;

        public PostController(IPostDataService postDataService)
        {
            _postDataService = postDataService;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> Get()
        {
            return await _postDataService.GetAllPosts();
        }
    }
```

But I am getting this error.

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'PostController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.

Here is my **Global.asax.cs**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            ContainerConfig.Configure();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }

    public static class ContainerConfig
    {
        private static IContainer _container;

        public static IContainer GetContainer()
        {
            if (_container != null)
                return _container;

            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<PostDataService>()
               .AsSelf()
               .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
               .AsImplementedInterfaces();

            _container = builder.Build();

            return _container;
        }

        public static IContainer Configure()
        {
            var container = GetContainer();

            var webApiResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = webApiResolver;

            return container;
        }
```

Can someone spot what I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707900/autofac-and-webapi-default-constructor-error

Comment: found it, I am missing,             `builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(PostController).Assembly)`.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm missing

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(PostController).Assembly).
```

Apparently, the controller also needs to be registered.

Comment: This, I got HTTP 404 errors when using OwinSelfHost along with autofac until I registered my controllers manually.